# Browsing network shares (SMB) causes spike in latency

Tags: windows-7, networking, network-shares

I've managed to narrow down an incredibly frustrating problem with intermittent latency spikes on one PC on my LAN (Win7 Pro x64) to connecting to SMB shares. I have other Win7 Pro PC's that don't have this problem. I'm guessing the intermittent occurrences are when the PC is scanning the LAN for available shares, but I can't be sure.

I can reliably trigger the issue by browsing to any shared drive/folder on the LAN from the machine in question. When I do this ping times on that machine (to any destination) spike to 500-2000ms and stay there for few minutes. After they come back down I can continue browsing the shared drive without issue. I disabled on-demand scanning of network drives in my A/V (Nod32). I even uninstalled the A/V completely and the issue still occurs.

It's a wireless connection, but I've all but eliminated the wireless and the router as sources of the problem.

What might cause a spike in latency when first connecting to a shared drive? I'm at a loss here...